# User authentication on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, authkit

I'm working on a project that will require user authentication. Currently I'm planning on running the project on GAE. For various reasons I'd rather have my own authentication system rather than use openid or google's built in authentication service. I've looked high and low for a library but can't seem to find anything. I've looked into AuthKit and even found a project called AuthKitGAE https://github.com/Roosmaa/AuthKitGAE; but the the project has almost no documentation and I don't have a ton of experience with Python so having no examples to work off of doesn't help. Do any of you know of any good authentication libraries for GAE or should I just set about trying to write my own?

Comment: Site note : To avoid implementing custom cookie or to use high performance google login system you might want to use openid provider and consumer both in same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ready to use django as a framework, you may get the django's auth system to work in it using django-nonrel:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine. They are working hard to get support for non relational databases like app engine's in django. I have actually tried this to host my django based website. It really works.

They have generated support for most of django features except for some.

Comment: Just found out this: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've played around with django a bit so I feel comfortable enough diving into development on there. I knew that django was kinda supported on GAE but I didn't realize that the entire background has now been ported over! Thanks for the info.

Comment: great @blcArmadillo. Go django!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Django in GAE you can write your own auth system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using a third-party framework, instead of `webapp`, [tipfy](http://tipfy.org) has some good extensions. For authentication, check [tipfy.ext.auth](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/). The documentation looks good.